# Transposing only a few columns into rows while leaving the rest columns as columns - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I am trying to transpose only the last two columns into rows. 
Here is my sample

```
    sample = {'ID' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
          'date' : [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
          '1st hour' : [111,121,131,211,221,231,311,321,331],
          '2nd hour' : [112,122,132,212,222,232,312,322,332],
          '3rd hour' : [113,123,133,213,223,233,313,323,333]
         }
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample)

sample_df
```

my output should be look like:

```
    sample = {'ID' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
          'date' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
          'value' : [111,112,113,121,122,123,131,132,133,211,212,213,221,222,223,231,232,233,311,312,313,321,322,323,331,332,333]
          }
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample)
sample_df
```

Basically, I just want the last 3 columns of the first data to be in rows not in columns.

If anyone can help me out on this, it will be awesome.
I appreciate that in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) + [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = sample_df.melt(id_vars=['ID','date']).drop('variable', 1).sort_values(['ID','date'])
#old version of pandas < 0.20.0
#df= pd.melt(sample_df, id_vars=['ID','date']).drop('variable', 1).sort_values(['ID','date'])
print (df.head(10))
    ID  date  value
0    1     1    111
9    1     1    112
18   1     1    113
1    1     2    121
10   1     2    122
19   1     2    123
2    1     3    131
11   1     3    132
20   1     3    133
3    2     1    211
```

Or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = sample_df.set_index(['ID','date'])
              .stack()
              .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
              .reset_index(name='value')
print (df.head(10))
   ID  date  value
0   1     1    111
1   1     1    112
2   1     1    113
3   1     2    121
4   1     2    122
5   1     2    123
6   1     3    131
7   1     3    132
8   1     3    133
9   2     1    211
```

Comment: oh wait, the second one works, but I'm getting an error with the first one saying that "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'melt'
"

Answer (score 2):

```
sample_df.set_index(['ID','date']).stack().reset_index().drop('level_2',1).rename(columns={0:'value'})
Out[559]: 
    ID  date  value
0    1     1    111
1    1     1    112
2    1     1    113
3    1     2    121
4    1     2    122
5    1     2    123
6    1     3    131
7    1     3    132
8    1     3    133
9    2     1    211
10   2     1    212
11   2     1    213
12   2     2    221
13   2     2    222
14   2     2    223
15   2     3    231
16   2     3    232
17   2     3    233
18   3     1    311
19   3     1    312
20   3     1    313
21   3     2    321
22   3     2    322
23   3     2    323
24   3     3    331
25   3     3    332
26   3     3    333
```

Comment: if you dont mind, can you please walk me through your code plz?

Comment: @YunTaeHwang set the index and stack equal to melt :-)

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic way to achieve this could be to flatten the last three columns as so:

```
>>> flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
>>> sample_df = [[111,112,113],[121,122,123],[131,132,133]]
>>> flatten(sample_df)
[111,112,113,121,122,123,131,132,133]
```

but the answer by jezrael might be a better choice working with panda dataframes.